# How to retrieve invalidated iterator?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

Well, the title says it all.

I have this piece of code:

```
std::list<vector<Plane>> list;
std::list<vector<Plane>>::iterator possible_planes_it;

...

for(possible_planes_it = list.begin(); possible_planes_it != 
    list.end(); possible_planes_it++)
{
        if(static_cast<float>(good_matches.size()) >= static_cast<float>((matches.size())*0.8))
        {
        if(possible_planes_it->back().getTimestamp() < count) // Means that there has not been a match found this round
        {
            possible_planes_it->push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
            possible_planes_it->back().setNumberOfGoodMatches(good_matches.size());
        }
        else
        {
            if(possible_planes_it->back().getNumberOfGoodMatches() < good_matches.size())
            {
                possible_planes_it->pop_back(); // If a better match has been found, remove the last vector entry and push the new one
                possible_planes_it->push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
                possible_planes_it->back().setNumberOfGoodMatches(good_matches.size());
            }
            else
            {
                list.push_back(vector<Plane>());
                list.back().push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        list.push_back(vector<Plane>());
        list.back().push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
    }
}
```

Somewhere in this for loop my iterators get invalidated so that it is stuck in an infinite loop. But how do I keep my iterators valid?

Comment: The title doesn't say it all.  We need to know what kind of container it is.

Comment: Sry, updated the code. Its a list of vectors.

Comment: And which iterator is invalidated?  Looks like the iterator in to the list?

Comment: How do you know the iterator is invalid?

Comment: Do you really have to post all that code to make your point?

Comment: invalid iterators will likely cause a seg-fault. Probably I posted correct answer

Comment: HAVE YOU TRIED FOR SMALL LIST/VECTOR SIZES? if your algorithm is Exponentiale then it will end, but in many years/centuries.
If you explain what that algorithm is trying to achieve, probably users can also suggest a better solution to your problem;)

Comment: spotted the bug. look in my answer you should check for "possible_planes.end" not "possible_planes_end"

Comment: Is `Plane` container aware? i.e. does it do something in the ctor/dtor relative to the list you are iterating? What is `list` that you suddenly start manipulating out of nowhere at the end?

Comment: BTW: This `push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));` may be expensive. If you are using a modern C++ compiler, you may want to replace with `emplace_back(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count);`

Comment: OR: you may want just `possible_planes_it->back() = Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count);` and let move-assignment have a crack at it in the case where you already know `back` exists in the container (i.e. it isn't empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to look at cppreference.com or cplusplus.com to see iterators validity

Basically each time you push_back data inside a vector there's the chance that it gets reallocated (unless you reserved enough size). When vector is reallocated EACH iterator to its elements is invalidated.

Iterators to list elements remains almost always valide even when inserting/erasing elements (only iterators TO erased elements become invalid).

The infinite loop could be the fact that you are adding 1 element to the list at each iteration

```
{
    list.push_back(vector<Plane>());
    list.back().push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
}
```

You have to prove that this code will never make the loop infinite. Just add a counter in there and print its value, then a counter to count number of loops and print it too.

Basically if you have iterator to last-1 list element, and you add an element, the last-1 list element iterator becomes last-2 list element iterator.

So you are maybe removing an element at begin and adding an element to the end, and your check for "end" iterator becomes like a dog biting its tail.

Also:

Invalidated iterators will cause a seg-fault first or later. **Probably your problem is not related to iterators validity**

Maybe you can use

```
list.push_front
```

?

**UPDATE REMOVED**

Comment: Your update doesn't make sense, `possible_planes_end` is not a typedef, it's a variable.  Presumably the OP sets it somewhere in his '...' section.  Also changing it to `possible_planes.end` won't work because that's not a valid variable name.

Comment: oh man, hate incomplete snippets, by the way it tecnically can still be something like a macro :D if there's no code showing what is that .

Answer (score 1):

Your iterators are not getting invalidated since for `std::list`

```
    Addition, removal and moving the elements within the list
    or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators.
    An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding
    element is deleted.
```

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).
Since you're not removing any elements, none of your iterators are invalidated.

What *is* happening is that your 'possible_planes_end' iterator is always pointing to the end of the list (even after adding elements) and so your problem can be reduced to this little snippet:

```
   #include <list>

    int main()
    {
        std::list<float> l;
        std::list<float>::iterator i = l.begin(), end = l.end();
        do
        {
            l.push_back(1);
            i++;
        }while(i != end);
    }
```

This runs forever because since the size of `l` keeps increasing by one each loop, `i` keeps pointing to the next-to-last element.  Forever.

Comment: this code will end first or later because is adding continuosly a value (first or later you will get std::bad_alloc) because you are not erasing elements

Comment: @DarioOO Even if your machine eventually runs out of memory, if that's the only stopping condition I think many people still consider that an infinite loop.  However, yes, this will not actually run forever.

Comment: it takes 0.2 seconds that loop to give a bad_alloc on my machine. I think he is both "removing" and "adding" nodes and that is in someway balanced and the loop really go forever